# Hide keyboard in applicationDidEnterBackground: - screenshot problem

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, animation, ios4, keyboard

When the home button gets pressed I want to hide the keyboard and restore my view to a sane state, so that when the app is started/foregrounded again, there is no textfield selected and the keyboard is hidden.

My app delegate has this implementation of the method:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [tabBarController.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

The keyboard does indeed get removed, but what I don't get is this: Apple's docs say that a snapshot of the app is taken *after* the method returns. However this poses a problem with the keyboard slide-down animation. Sometimes when the app is started again for a short moment it shows the keyboard half-way down. I assume the screenshot is taken before the animation was finished.

What would I do to solve this, introduce a short timer in the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method? I wonder if there is a "cleaner" solution.

Comment: Have you tried to do that stuff in applicationWillResignActive: ?

Comment: Yes, same problem. I have put that endEditing in applicationDidEnterBackground, applicationDidResignActive and applicationWillTerminate in turn. I have also tried putting [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5] after it - that leads to a black screen shown when the app comes up again instead of the half finished animation. Not sure which one is better yet...

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this but what about turning animations off just before you resign the keyboard:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
     [tabBarController.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

If this works you need to turn them back on in applicationWillEnterForeground