# Show splash screen when application enters background

Tags: ios, cordova, background, splash-screen

I am writing an application using phonegap for iOS. I am trying to show splash screen when application enters to background.

`(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` [...]

In  `applicationWillResignActive:` I am calling a JavaScript function and using cordova's method `cordova.exec(null,null, "SplashScreen, "show", [])` to show splash screen. But it seems like, this is not working.

When I resume the app, the application brings the previous state first and then switches to splash screen, but I want to show the splash screen when the app resumes. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: anarnth, how did you call a javaScript function in your objective c class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got this working:

```
- (void) applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  //Call to JS to change to splash
 [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.02
}
```

Allow the current runloop to run for a brief moment

For more information on the answer please check the below link:

[The exact moment iOS takes the view snapshot when entering background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937998/the-exact-moment-ios-takes-the-view-snapshot-when-entering-background)

Answer (score 0):

As you've experienced, the actual view hierarchy will not be modified until the app resumes activity.  Try setting a property/variable in -applicationWillResignActive: that indicates you should show the splash screen when the app becomes active again, then actually show it immediately in -applicationDidBecomeActive:

Comment: Matt, Thanks for the reply.  I tried your suggestion. But when the app is brought to foreground i still the see previous state first and then it switches to splash.

Comment: Does your "show" method show it animated?  Because, you might try to make the change happen without animation, and force a layout/display.  Also, if you're having trouble doing this kind of think in the app delegate methods, you could try putting it in viewWillAppear on your root view controller.  Sorry for the false lead.