# iOS takes a screenshot of App every time it is sent to the background - How would I secure my App?

Tags: ios, iphone, security, nsdocumentdirectory

Every time security of Apps comes up, it turns out a lot of people are unaware of this being an issue. For instance, iOS takes screen-shot of visible screen every time our App gets backgrounded and it is stored in local storage.

Now that's the thing I want to get rid of. I am developing an App that does online financial transactions and I want my App be very powerful in terms of security aspect. Here is the path where the screenshot is being stored when my App gets backgrounded.

---

**Path:** /private/var/mobile/Applications/15980ADD-B269-4EBE-9F52- B6275AFB195A/Library/Caches/Snapshots/com.ABC.myAppName/screenshotName.PNG

---

This is the image which is being stored that looks very critical:

[image]

---

Even more critical scenario will be if user has entered his/her Credit/Debit card number including CVV2 number and other essential information and might have forced App in background for a while.

I have been doing a little search on that and I got to know that, for an attacker to be able to leverage this attack, there are two ways for him to gain access to that:

- The attacker needs physical access to the device with the intent of
  jail breaking.
- Needs to be on the same network as user who has jail broken the
  device and attempt to access the device remotely.

What could have I done to avoid this being possible? Is there any solution that can avoid an attacker getting access to the sensitive information in this way?

Also I have gotten advice to enable a blank screenshot or delete the screenshot for the application, when the application is backgrounded. But, I don't have any idea what to choose and how to do it properly. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controlling the screenshot in the iOS 7 multitasking switcher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959411/controlling-the-screenshot-in-the-ios-7-multitasking-switcher)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apple told us to hide secure info before going to `background`, so just give it a image to hide everything:

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if(needToHide){
    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:[self.window frame]];
    [_imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"HideME.png"]];
    [self.window addSubview:_imageView];
    }
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if(_imageView != nil) {
        [_imageView removeFromSuperview];
        _imageView = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Then what will I see when I bring my App back to foreground state ? Will I see "HideME.png" image or actual screen ?

Comment: It would remove the image once the app become active.
Actually, it is just a fast workaround. You could hide the text fields in someway rather than showing a image.

Comment: Thanks Horst, I have used this fast workaround presently and it works as a charm. Answer Accepted.

Answer (score 26):

I can suggest a couple of things:

1)  you know when your app is about to be put into the `background`, via the application delegate method:

```
- (void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

[That's the exact moment the snapshot is generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937998/the-exact-moment-ios-takes-the-view-snapshot-when-entering-background).  Why not change your view to be something different or more "secure"?

2)

If you want the "secure" (or bogus) snapshot to be ignored when you bring the app back to foreground, you can use "[`[UIApplication ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch)".

3)

You can also add "[`UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW23)" into your app's Info.plist when putting your app into the background, which will kill your app entirely and not save a snapshot.

Comment: I really came to know new things. UPVOTED

Comment: Just a note on point 3: Xcode translates "UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend" into "Application does not run in the background". If set to YES then the app simply won't run in the background, but it does not quit entirely. iOS still takes a screenshot and the app still shows in the task switcher.