# Quit MPMoviePlayer on entering background in iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, back, mpmovieplayer

MPMoviePlayer is presented on RootViewController.On entering background, I have popped the MPMoviePlayerController.
But on entering foreground,the movie player screen is splashed for a second and then disappears.

What I need is not to show the movie player view on entering foreground.
Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controlling the screenshot in the iOS 7 multitasking switcher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959411/controlling-the-screenshot-in-the-ios-7-multitasking-switcher)

Comment: Hope this will help u.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937998/the-exact-moment-ios-takes-the-view-snapshot-when-entering-background

Try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the system takes a snapshot of the application’s main window when an application moves on to the background, which is presented when you enter foreground.

Hope this will help you to understand things better.

[Prevent iOS from taking screen capture of app before going into background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520076/how-not-to-allow-the-ios-from-taking-a-screen-capture-of-your-app-before-going-i)

[The exact moment iOS takes the view snapshot when entering background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937998/the-exact-moment-ios-takes-the-view-snapshot-when-entering-background)